# How to use the find command such that it matches from the innermost directory?

Tags: find

Say that I have the following file

```
this/is/my/file.txt
```

Can I search this file given that I only know the file is in `/my/` directory ?

Comment: Do you want to search *for* (`find`) that file, or search *in* that file?

Comment: I want to find that file, eg. I want to find `this/is/my/file.txt` given that I know `file.txt` is in `/my/` directory and find by the name of the file is not feasible because there are many `file.txt` in many other directory

Comment: What is your operating system? What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

### How do I `find` a file in the innermost directory?

You can use `find` to look for a specific file (`file.txt`), and it will recurse for you (accorind to options specified). But what if you have two `file.txt`s, and only want to match **one**, say for use in a script? Enter `awk`, `sort`, `head` and `cut`:

```
find /my/ -type f -name file.txt | awk -F/ '{ print NF-1, $0 }' | sort -nr | head -n1 | cut -d " " -f2
```

This will return one result - the *deepest* match - or none.

### Explanation

- `find` in `/my/` all regular files (`-type f`) `-name`d `file.txt`
- pass to `awk`, and get it to count the number of directories (depth) by setting the field separator to `/` (`-F/`), and prefixing that to the result (`print NF-1, $0`)
- `sort` that numerically, descending from greatest (ie most directories) first
- take only one result (`head -n1`)
- strip off the depth count (`cut -d " " -f2`)

There may be a shorter way to do it, but this will return the deepest result. It assumes slashes `/` for directory demarcation, but I think we can allow that. Tested on `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release` (and `GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release` on OSX), and doesn't rely too much on GNUisms.